# this code is deadlocked.how can i solve it?

Tags: java, deadlock

Is there any way to solve this code?

I cannot go past the runtime ...
  and **why is this happening?**

```
public void method1(){
    synchronized(String.class){
        System.out.println("Aquired lock on String.class object");

        synchronized (Integer.class) {
            System.out.println("Aquired lock on Integer.class object");
        }
    }
}

public void method2(){
    synchronized(Integer.class){
        System.out.println("Aquired lock on Integer.class object");

        synchronized (String.class) {
            System.out.println("Aquired lock on String.class object");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/LCK07-J.+Avoid+deadlock+by+requesting+and+releasing+locks+in+the+same+order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When two or more threads waiting for each other to release lock and get stuck for infinite time , situation is called deadlock**

The real reason for deadlock is **not multiple threads but the way they access lock** , if you provide an ordered access then problem will be resolved.

I sorted out your code.

```
public void method1(){
synchronized(Integer.class){
System.out.println("Aquired lock on Integer.class object");

synchronized (String.class) {
System.out.println("Aquired lock on String.class object");
}
}
}

public void method2(){
synchronized(Integer.class){
System.out.println("Aquired lock on Integer.class object");

synchronized (String.class) {
System.out.println("Aquired lock on String.class object");
}
}
}
```

Now there would not be any deadlock because both method is accessing lock on Integer and String object in same order . so if thread A acquires lock on Integer object , thread B will not proceed until thread A releases Integer lock , same way thread A will not be blocked even if thread B holds String lock because now thread B will not expect thread A to release Integer lock to proceed further.

Comment: The code worked. Can you please tell me about the race condition happening here ?

Comment: Its more of a design issue. What if the OP wanted a lock on the String class only if he had locked the Integer class, in the first case. And in the second case, if he wanted the reverse of it. This *does* happen in real time applications.

Comment: @TheLostMind: This does happen in real applications, but it is a design issue. No one "wants" to lock anything. Locks are a means to achieve an end, namely thread-safe code. Mandating that String class can only be locked if Integer class is already locked is a good solution. Yes, it reduces concurrency, but it avoids deadlocks.

Comment: The code works and answer improved my concept. Thanks @Thilo and deepanshu

Comment: @Thilo - This will indeed prevent a deadlock. I was merely pointing out the fact that this reduces concurrency (which you have already mentioned). Which I must accept is a trade-off anybody could die for.. :P

Comment: @DeepanshuBedi - I had understood your answer (and +1 was already credited to your account :P).. I was merely pointing out the hit on efficiency (incorrectly)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Replace the order of the synchronnized block.

```
public void method1(){


synchronized (Integer.class) {
        System.out.println("Aquired lock on Integer.class object");
        }
    synchronized(String.class){
    System.out.println("Aquired lock on String.class object");


    }
    }

    public void method2(){
    synchronized(Integer.class){
    System.out.println("Aquired lock on Integer.class object");

    synchronized (String.class) {
    System.out.println("Aquired lock on String.class object");
    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you can have multiple threads acquiring the same *set of locks* (i.e. more than one lock), but *not in the same order*.

So you can end up with Thread A having locked Integer,  Thread B having locked String, and both threads waiting for the lock the other has (and won't release). Deadlock!

The ideal solution is *lock ordering*: Always acquire the locks in the same order. Depending on how complex your code is, this may be difficult to implement, but since it prevents deadlocks, you should give it a try.

Comment: but what if the OP wants the locks in the order he has written ?

Comment: No one "wants" to lock anything. Locks are a means to achieve an end, namely thread-safe code. Mandating that String class can only be locked if Integer class is already locked is a good solution. Yes, it reduces concurrency, but it avoids deadlocks.